# Reshaping the data with mix of long and wide to long

Tags: r, reshape

I think the question might be simple, please help me with this.

I have a dataset like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NkPn.png)

and I need to reshape it like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K59LU.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question (28 mins ago ...) you can found some solutions on this question [How to transform R data from long-ish to wide-ish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58909012/how-to-transform-r-data-from-long-ish-to-wide-ish).

Comment: Hi dc37, I appreciate taking time in going through my question post. My dataset consists mix of wide and long. Pls help me transform to long

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your datasets. Based on your images, your initial dataset does not look like R data.frame

Comment: The image 1 is the data I have and image 2 is the data I need to transform to. I need to do this in R for some automation purpose. I am not able to find any minimal code to do this in R. In excel, I can only do manual paste transpose function which is time consuming and not good to automate.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest creating a column name for each observation (count) based on the values from the Location, City, CustomerId and partner rows. e.g. `paste0(Location, City, CustomerId, partner, collapse  = '/')`
Consequently, use `reshape2::melt` to "melt" the dataframe to long format. 
Afterwards, use:

```
tidyr::separate(
  data, 
  "collapsedColName",  
  into = c("Location", "City", "CustomerId", "partner"),
  sep = "/"
  )
```

to recreate those variables.

Comment: Thanks Jeroen Colin